# Resize image from base64

Tags: html, canvas, base64, filereader

I use FileReader for get base64 code of image.
If i use canvas and put in to canvas base64. Than apply resize for canvas. I get new base64 code of new image?

Code sample.

```
reader.onloadend = function(event) {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("temp_canvas");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
          var ratio = (imageObj.width > imageObj.height)?Math.ceil(imageObj.width / imageObj.height):Math.ceil(imageObj.height / imageObj.width);
          console.log(ratio);
          if(imageObj.width > 512) {
              imageObj.width = 512
              imageObj.height = imageObj.width * ratio;
          }
          console.log(imageObj.width);
          console.log(imageObj.height);
          $(canvas).attr('width',imageObj.width);
          $(canvas).attr('height',imageObj.height);
          context.drawImage(imageObj,0,0,imageObj.width,imageObj.height);
      }
      imageObj.src = event.target.result;
      $('.image-for-crop').attr('src',event.target.result);
      $('#dialog-foto').dialog({modal:true});
  }
```

If i do  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

My main question is: "Any time when i change canvas : crop,resize e.t.c. base64 code of this canvas change too?"

Comment: Can you add some more information? Im not sure what your asking

Comment: Base64 is not an image format, it's an encoding for binary data.  Encoded in your base64 is some type of image data; it could be any format, like jpg, png, ... It could even be raw data.

Comment: I put more information about question.

Comment: Is there an option to manipulate the binary data to make some image modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any change you do using `2d context` API will appear in result of `canvas.toDataURL()`. However `DOM` operations like resizing your <canvas>  element  (example `myCanvas.style.width = 100`) will do no changes to pixels data of it.